# In VTK, how to get the world coordinate of a Prop?

Tags: python, vtk

I created a cube in SolidWorks and exported it to STL file.(Te cube is 50mm to the right of the origin) Then I used the VTK class vtkSTLReader to read this file and render it in the render window.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7d5n.png)

However, when I  called the function GetPosition(), it always returned (0,0,0). In my opinion,it should be (50,0,0). [The VTK class reference](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkProp3D.html) explains this function is to "Get the position of the Prop3D in world coordinates". It make me confused. I don't know where the problem is.

```
import vtk
sr = vtk.vtkSTLReader()
sr.SetFileName("cube.stl")

stlMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
stlMapper.SetInputConnection(sr.GetOutputPort())

stlActor = vtk.vtkLODActor()
stlActor.SetMapper(stlMapper)

# Create the Renderer, RenderWindow, and RenderWindowInteractor
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

# Add the actors to the render; set the background and size
ren.AddActor(stlActor)
ren.SetBackground(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
renWin.SetSize(500, 500)

print stlActor.GetPosition()

iren.Initialize()
renWin.Render()
iren.Start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, unless you change the position of the **prop (actor)**, it will remain at 0,0,0. This prop represents the geometry, in your case a cube, which has one of it's nodes defined at 50,0,0, but that is of no consequence to the position of the prop. In fact, there is no way for that one point (position of the prop) to be tied to any one node of the underlying geometry - how would it decide which of the nodes of the cube it is? Instead, it is a reference point and if it is 0,0,0, it means your geometry will be rendered at exactly the same coordinates at which the geometry is defined (which you can get as `sr.GetOutputPort().GetPoints()` or look into your stl file directly). Basically, the GetPosition() gives you the translation part of the transformation matrix that is applied to your points.

To answer your question, as I've already said, you can get the points of the geometry from `sr.GetOutputPort().GetPoints()` which are your world coordinates for that geometry assuming there are no transformations applied. If you are concerned about some transformations, you can either define your own transformations on the actor (Set/GetUserTransform) or use the camera's ModelMatrix (ren.GetActiveCamera().GetModelMatrix) and then use the vtkTransform class to apply those transofrmations to any coordinates you want to get their "image" after those transformations.